# Leibniz integral rule proof correct?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am a high school student writing a paper (that fellow high school students should be able to understand).

On part of the paper, I need to use the Leibniz integral rule, but can't just name drop it.

Is the following working correct?:

$$  s=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}F[x,g(\epsilon),g'(\epsilon)]dx $$
The length $s$ is now a function of $\epsilon$. Hence, we can differentiate it:
$$ \frac{ds}{d\epsilon}=\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}F[x,g(\epsilon),g'(\epsilon)]dx  $$

From the first principles of differentiation:
$$  \frac{ds}{d\epsilon}= \lim_{\Delta \epsilon \to 0} \frac{I(\epsilon+\Delta \epsilon)- I (\epsilon)}{\Delta \epsilon} $$
$$ =\lim_{\Delta \epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta\epsilon}\left[\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}F[x,g(\epsilon+\Delta\epsilon),g'(\epsilon+\Delta\epsilon)]dx-\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}F[x,g(\epsilon),g'(\epsilon)]dx\right]$$

$$ = \lim_{\Delta \epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta\epsilon}\left[\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}F[x,g(\epsilon+\Delta\epsilon),g'(\epsilon+\Delta\epsilon)] - F[x,g(\epsilon),g'(\epsilon)]dx\right]$$

$$ = \lim_{\Delta \epsilon \to 0}\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}\frac{F[x,g(\epsilon+\Delta\epsilon),g'(\epsilon+\Delta\epsilon)]-F[x,g(\epsilon),g'(\epsilon)]}{\Delta\epsilon}dx$$
Hence, we are back to the first principle definition of a derivative. Therefore, the equation can be simplified using a partial derivative:
$$ \frac{ds}{d\epsilon}=\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}} \frac {\partial F[x,g(\epsilon),g'(\epsilon)]}{d\epsilon} dx $$
A partial derivative is used since $F[x,g(\epsilon),g'(\epsilon)]$ is a multi-variable function.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The bottleneck here is that you change $\lim$ and $\int$ in the last equation. But the property you are talking about is true when for example $|x_1| < \infty, |x_2| < \infty$ and $F, g$ are good enough functions

Comment: Ok thanks. both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are defined constants in my problem. $s$ is a functional and $g$ is a continuous function

Comment: The issue is when two limits can be exchanged. Unfortunately, this cannot always be done. All you've done is converted the derivative to its definition so that we can explicitly see one of the limits. But the other limit - in the definition of the integral -remains hidden, and you have given no justification for exchanging the limits, so you haven't accomplished anything. A full justification is going to be beyond your target audience. Rather than trying to reprove this widely known result, "name-drop" it, and provide a reference to a book giving a proof.

Comment: But also make sure that you have justified *applying* it by ensuring that the functions meet the required conditions. $g$ needs to be continuously differentiable, not just continuous. $F$ will need to be continuously differentiable in its second and third arguments, and continuous in the first. (Some loosening of these conditions is possible. See the exact statement of the theorem in your reference to be sure what conditions you must meet.)

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Ok I see, I will do that then. I'm using it when deriving the Euler-Lagrange equation (copying from a textbook which uses it), which requires F to be a path between to fixed points ( so continuous).

Comment: You are differentiating $F$. That means $F$ has to be differentiable, not just continuous. Continuity of that derivative is generally sufficient to allow interchange of the integral and derivative, though weaker conditions can also be made to work - again, find a reference for the theorem and see what conditions it requires.